# Illegal start of expression string

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program that reverses the text lines in a file. I am still learning java and I am new to this. My program was erroring because I made a variable inside a loop and tried to access it outside. I tried adding the preffix "public" before declaring the string variable but when I try to compile it it points to the "public" and says illegal start of expression. Can someone please tell me why this is erroring and or how to fix it.

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class FileReverser
    {
     public static void main(String[] args)
     throws FileNotFoundException
{
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("File to Reverse: ");
    String inputFileName = console.next();

    System.out.print("Output File: ");
    String outputFileName = console.next();

    FileReader reader = new FileReader(inputFileName);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(reader);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputFileName);

    int number = 0;

    while (in.hasNextLine())
    {
        String line = in.nextLine();
        public String[] lines;
        lines[number] = line;
        number++;
    }
    int subtract = 0;
    for (int i;i>lines.length;i++)
    {
        out.println(lines[(lines.length-subtract)]);
        subtract++;
    }

    out.close();

    }
    }
```

Comment: First thing to fix: the indentation. Having properly indented code makes everything *much* easier to understand.

Comment: people, please don't downvote this... he has a genuine problem, if someone else stumbles upon this we can avoid a similar question.

Comment: @AnanthaSharma nice thinking hope other users think like u.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problems:

- You're declaring `lines` with the `public` modifier, which is only for instance/static variables, not local variables.
- You're never *initializing* `lines`
- You're trying to use `lines` outside its scope (which is currently the `while` loop)
- You're trying to use `i` without initializing it, here:

  ```
  for (int i;i>lines.length;i++)
  ```
- Your `if` condition is the wrong way round; you would want to continue while `i` is *less* than `lines.length`
- `subtract` is initially 0, so accessing `lines[lines.length - subtract]` will throw an exception (as it's outside the bounds of the array)

You can fix these with the following code:

```
// See note later
String[] lines = new String[1000];

while (in.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = in.nextLine();
    lines[number] = line;
    number++;
}
// Get rid of subtract entirely... and only start off at "number"
// rather than lines.length, as there'll be a bunch of null elements
for (int i = number - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    out.println(lines[i]);
}
```

Now that will work for up to 1000 lines - but it's a pain to have that limitation. It would be better just to use a `List<String>`:

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
while (in.hasNextLine()) {
    lines.add(in.nextLine());
}
```

Then you'd need to use `size()` instead of `length`, and use `get` instead of the array indexer to access the values - but it would be cleaner code IMO.

Answer (score 0):

This is a scope issue. `lines` should be declared outside of the while loop. By putting `lines` in the while loop, it is only available inside that loop. If you move it outside, the scope of `lines` will be in the main method.

The scope of a variable is the portion of a program that can access the variable.

Here's lecture notes on variables and scope from a class at Berkeley. Give it a read, if you have the time.
http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/4/lec/08

Answer (score 0):

Access modifiers (`public`, `private`, `protected`) are applicable for class members (method or fields) only.

If you want to access variable outside its scope limited by `{` and `}` this means that you defined the variable in wrong scope. For example if you defined loop and variable `x` inside and then want to use it outside the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    .....
    int x = 6;
    .....
}

int y = x; // compilation error
```

... you actually wanted to define this variable before the loop:

```
int x = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    .....
    x = 6;
    .....
}

int y = x; // not variable is available here
```